# How to use EasyDialogs create a progress bar without title bar and 'Cancel' button?

Tags: python

I have a job starting some Microsoft Windows services, because this a very timing process, to improve the user experience, i want to use a progress bar to show the progress. I know there is a tool called EasyDialogs, it can provide virious dialogs like progress bar, but they all have the title bar and a Cancel button. That's not what I want, can some one tell me how to create a progress without title bar and a Cancel button?

Currently, I am using EasyDialogs-for-Windows 46691.0, the following code to create the progress bar:

```
bar = EasyDialogs.ProgressBar('XXXXXX Tool', maxval=7, label='Service Starting, please wait...', id=263)
```

This bar have the title bar and a Cancel button, or someone can tell me how to modify this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EasyDialogs could not do this is because, it used Windows API: CreateDialogIndirectParamA to create window:

```
self.hwnd = user32.CreateDialogIndirectParamA(0, resources[id], 0, self.wrappedDlgProc, 0)
```

The second parameter: resources[id] is the window layout, it is using binary string to do this. And currently, only 7 modes supported (id 263 is the progress bar), but it has the title bar and the "Cancel" button. I have to change to use tkinter to create it manually.

First, I created a root window, and set it as invisibility:

```
root = Tk()
root.wm_withdraw()
```

Then created the sub-window to put the progress bar:

```
main = Toplevel(root)
main.overrideredirect(1) # The window without title bar
main.resizable(False, False)
main.wm_geometry("400x60")
```

And the put the progress bar to this window:

```
bar_value = tk.IntVar()
self.bar = ttk.Progressbar(self.win, maximum=7, length=100, variable=self.bar_value)
```

Updating the value, When my backend program is running:

```
self.bar_value.set(val)
```

All was well done, cheers!